# Postgresql slow remote execution when using alternative clients

Tags: postgresql, performance, remote, query-performance

I noticed a strange perfomance issue when running sql queries on a remote Postgresql Server.

Everything good when using psql:

**Connect via ssh and run things locally**

```
$ ssh user@example.org
user@example:~$ psql -h localhost -U database -d database
database=# \timing
Timing is on.
database=# explain analyse select * from mytable where my_field='14123';
Time: 1646.577 ms (00:01.647)
database=# select * from mytable where my_field='14123';
Time: 1642.361 ms (00:01.642)
```

**Forward postgresql to a local port and connect locally**

```
$ ssh -L 1111:localhost:5432 user@example.org
$ psql -h localhost -p 1111 -d database -U database
database=# explain analyse select * from mytable where my_field='14123';
Time: 1669.424 ms (00:01.669)
database=# select * from mytable where my_field='14123';
Time: 1703.183 ms (00:01.703)
```

However, when I use GUI clients such as DBeaver or DataGrip I get the following timings:

### DBeaver

**Use option "SSH tunnel" in DBeaver**

```sql
explain analyse select * from mytable where my_field='14123';
-- Execution time: 1665.447 ms
select * from mytable where my_field='14123';
-- Execution time: 6475 ms
```

**"Direct" connection with locally forwarded port**

```sql
explain analyse select * from mytable where my_field='14123';
-- Execution time: 1617.330 ms
select * from mytable where my_field='14123';
-- Execution time: 6370 ms
```

### DataGrip

**Use option "SSH tunnel" in DataGrip**

```
sql> explain analyse select * from mytable where my_field='14123'
execution: 1 s 561 ms, fetching: 10 ms
sql> select * from mytable where my_field='14123' LIMIT 35
execution: 6 s 360 ms, fetching: 60 ms
```

**"Direct" connection with locally forwarded port**

```
sql> explain analyse select * from mytable where my_field='14123'
execution: 1 s 900 ms, fetching: 22 ms
sql> select * from mytable where my_field='14123' LIMIT 35
execution: 6 s 565 ms, fetching: 107 ms
```

Why are the timings so much worse when using these GUI applications? (6s instead of 1.5s) DataGrip's output suggests that it isn't the data being transferred, and in fact the select only yields 35 rows, which are < 100kb in total. Also it's **much** slower in both cases, and it takes about the same time in all the unexpected cases. What can cause this? Maybe something in the JDBC driver?

I connect to the server via VPN and then use an SSH-Tunnel to access the Postgresql server. Both the VPN server and database server are under little load and are very close to me (same city). 
Postgresql version is 10 and runs on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Can you set either "log_min_duration_statement" or "auto_explain.log_min_duration" to see if the server itself agrees about these long execution times?

Comment: Those `explain` timings look suspicious. What is the time needed for `SELECT 42;`? (I get 0.2 ms on localhost, and 30 ms in the cloud.)

Comment: @jjanes Yes, the server reports the same timings.  (https://pastebin.com/Shk8abRa)

Comment: @CL. Takes 15ms

Comment: I have the same problem with DataGrip connecting to MySql over SSH tunnel. A select executed over DataGrip takes around 13s: `4 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 12 s 964 ms (execution: 12 s 922 ms, fetching: 42 ms)` but the same query executed locally on the server takes 100ms: `4 rows in set (0.01 sec)`.